# Don't count some application celullar data consume

Tags: mobile-data

I have a cellular data plan which allows me to use 3.5GB of mobile internet, using WhatsApp and Facebook with no data charge.

Android counts always the data consumption for Facebook and WhatsApp. Is there a way to make the SO not-count these two apps consumption?

PD: Sorry if my english isn't that good, still learning

Comment: Your phone and your carrier count for data usage differently. I don't think there is a way to exclude some apps to the counter.

Comment: Not even a third-party app? I've searched and haven't found.

Comment: Give a try to `Onavo count`. It shows how much data you use on each app.